# How can I compare an array of objects with a the content of a var

Tags: javascript, compare

I have an array of objects of the following form:

```
jsonParseEntityVariables = [
{"id":0, "text": []},
{"id":1, "text": []},
{"id":2, "text": []}
];
```

I also have a var with name `entity_variables.currentId` in which I store an ID

How can I compare all `jsonParseEntityVariables.id` with `entity_variables.currentId` to decide that `entity_variables.currentId` is not equal at all to any `jsonParseEntityVariables.id`?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. (You may -- or may not -- have *started* with JSON, but by the time you're doing the above, you're not dealing with JSON anymore and it's irrelevant to the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `Array#every`. If none of the `ids` in the json are equal to given value, it will return `true`.

```js
var jsonParseEntityVariables = [{"id":0, "text": []},{"id":1, "text": []},{"id":2, "text": []}],
    currentId = 4;

    console.log(jsonParseEntityVariables.every(v => v.id != currentId));
```

or `Array#some`, that will return `false` if there are no equal values. If there's even one matched element, it will return `true`.

```js
var jsonParseEntityVariables = [{"id":0, "text": []},{"id":1, "text": []},{"id":2, "text": []}],
    currentId = 4;

    console.log(jsonParseEntityVariables.some(v => v.id == currentId));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array of objects. You can readily check if their `id` values do, or don't, matcy `entity_variables.currentId` with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
if (jsonParseEntitiesVariables.some(function(e) { return e.id === entity_variables.currentId;})) {
    // At least one matched
} else {
    // None matched
}
```

Or with an ES2015+ arrow function:

```
if (jsonParseEntitiesVariables.some(e => e.id === entity_variables.currentId)) {
    // At least one matched
} else {
    // None matched
}
```

If you want to know *which* entry matched, [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) would be what you're looking for:

```
var match = jsonParseEntitiesVariables.find(e => e.id === entity_variables.currentId);
if (match) {
    // Found it, `match` contains it
} else {
    // Not found
}
```

`findIndex` works the same way, but returns the index of the found entry (or -1 if not found).

Answer (score 0):

var jsonParseEntityVariables = [{"id":0, "text": []},{"id":1, "text": []},{"id":2, "text": []}],
    currentId = 1;
console.log(jsonParseEntityVariables.every(jsonParseEntityVariables => jsonParseEntityVariables.id != currentId));

Answer (score 0):

This code checks for duplicate id-s of your id.

```
var id_duplicate = false;
for (i in jsonParseEntityVariables){
    if (jsonParseEntityVariables[i].id === entity_variables.currentId){
        id_duplicate = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note! your `jsonParseEntityVariables` is a number. make sure that `entity_variables.currentId` is also a number.